# Manifest screen support Entry for Device only and Tablet Only

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, android-screen-support, android-market-filtering

What should be the manifest entry of an Android application which supports only device not tablet. Device size can be vary but the maximum should be 7 Inch.

I have developed an application different build for device and tablet now i want to launch both build in market but following manifest entry supports 10 Inch tablet too.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="6"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />


<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

I want to restrict user to download this build on 10 Inch Tablet, and 10 Inch tablet build should not be download on other than 10 Inch tablet.

Please suggest me the perfect manifest entry for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying all possible combination of support screen and SDK version i am still not able to restrict 10 inch tablet device to download that application.

If you just want to exclude 10 Inch tablet device just exclude all tablet device manually from supporting device list.

If you have another build for the same application upload that build too and keep its version code higher than device build. Version code must not be conflict in any case. Because if multiple apk support for any device the higher version apk will support that device.

When i upload both build in my google account following note/warning appears to help me:

```
"Warning: Multiple active APKs support some of the same devices. If a device is supported by more than one APK, it will receive the one with the higher version."
```

and following the manifest entry of my application:

for Device Build:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="6"
android:targetSdkVersion="8" />


<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

For Tablet Build:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="6"
android:targetSdkVersion="8" />


<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="false"
android:normalScreens="false"
android:resizeable="false"
android:smallScreens="false"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: My app need to support all android mobiles and tablets... so plz suggest the sdk version and support screen values...

Comment: @Krishnakant Dalal hey I am using this, but it still allows me to install application in tablets.. I am trying to run it on eclipse emulator and it allows me to run on tablet..

Answer (score 1):

You should use this attribute in your manifest

`android:largestWidthLimitDp="enter mobile pixel value which above you want restrict."`

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="500"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Comment: But this is not available for sdk version 8.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

The code to disable extra large screens is

```
<supports-screens
 android:xlargeScreens="false"
 />
```

From what I'm seeing, this still allows you to run the app on a tablet device from Eclipse but should disable it at publish time.

Comment: I published my application for device with the above manifest entries and i am still able to download application on 10 Inch Tablet.

Comment: Just set your target to 9 or higher and you can use xlarge. Any device that is below api level 9 should not be able to declare itself as xlarge and therefore will still be able to install your app. So try this, and let me know.

Comment: So are you still stuck on this problem?