# What is the manifest file entry

Tags: android

What should be the manifest entry of an Android application which supports only 7 inch, 10 inch  tablet?
And it is reverse to following question
[Manifest screen support Entry for Device only and Tablet Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673881/manifest-screen-support-entry-for-device-only-and-tablet-only)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something like the following. Please read the Google guide to understand the Options and the consequences: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

"As per the details from android developer site,  Android groups actual device sizes into four generalized groups small,normal,large and extra large. Also the density of the devices determines the categorization of android devices.

On setting the value the tag "supports-screens" you can handle this

try this

```
    <manifest ... >
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
...
<application ... >
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screenSize=“large” android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize=“large android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize=“xlarge” android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize=“xlarge android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

[Refer this android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps)